# Can I replace this old mercury thermostat with a digital one for wood/oil furnace?

Tags: electrical, hvac, thermostat, furnace, oil

I recently moved into a house that was built around 1999, and it has an old Newmac wood/oil combo furnace that seems to be the original heating equipment. It has two separate thermostats in the kitchen, one for each fuel. They are the analog and both contain mercury tubes.

As the heating season starts I'm realizing they don't work in a helpful way, the temperature reading and controls just seem wrong and they basically just function as manual on/off switches for the fan. Regardless of how well they work, not having the ability to program it at all is driving me crazy so I'm hoping I can replace them with more modern digital ones. Ideally something with wifi or bluetooth so I don't have to trek downstairs in the middle of the night if I want to turn on/off the heat. At the very least I would like to be able to program the oil side for when we are away.

I'm hoping to get some advice about what my thermostat options are for this system. I did some looking around and I'm almost certain the model I have is one from the Newmac multi-fuel CL Series and luckily the manual is available here: https://img1.wsimg.com/blobby/go/bec15ddb-2b98-417f-a942-3bc32a098b38/downloads/CL86-96C%2C%20CL86-96G%2C%20CL%20115-170C%2C%20CL115-170G%20EN.pdf?ver=1604329839533

It contains this wiring diagram and I found that the model #s listed here on the Honeywell/White Rodgers components matches the labels on my equipment exactly:
[image]

Looking at the way the Wood/Oil thermostats in this diagram are hooked up, this makes sense because when I look closely the wood one has 2 wires on the left terminal hooked up and 1 wire on the right, but the oil thermostat just looks to have 1 left and 1 right wire. So I'm assuming that extra left wire on the wood thermostat is connected to the left terminal of the oil one. (first pic is wood, second is oil).
[image: wood thermostat]
[image: oil thermostat]

In addition, this is what I see at the back of the furnace, what appears to be the component labelled 'Trans/Relay; in the diagram. Those letters are D, O and C:
[image: relay]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use the wood for heating?  Usually how they work was if using wood, then the oil would only come if the heat in the house dropped below what the oil was set at.  The wood thermostat would be the main one for controlling house temperature and oil as backup.  Do not know if newer digitals can handle dual/separate heat sources, might need two or just one for the oil if not using wood.  Have furnace checked out anyway.

Comment: This question might help some, for wood/electric, but idea is the same.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/147477/connecting-wood-electric-furnace-to-smart-thermostat?rq=1

Comment: The "heat pump" setting with emergency heat functions the same as @crip659 explains.  It turns on the heat pump for heating, but if that can't keep up and the temp continues to drop, the secondary or emergency heat will kick on.  That might work, but at that point you're using it in a way it wasn't designed and it might not work perfectly.  Either way you are going to have to run a new wire to provide power to the smart thermostat.

Comment: Yes we are planning on burning wood eventually (but not right now since it's shoulder season, and not while we are away from home).

Comment: I did see that other multi fuel question but the wiring seemed significantly different. Have been doing a lot of research even just since posting and there doesn't seem to be a modern thermostat specifically made for these multi fuel units. I don't mind if I need to have 2 independent thermostats since I can manage that, I don't even mind if I have to  move them to the furnace room (if I can control them remotely) and buy a c wire kit (eg nest power connector). Just trying to figure out if that's possible and if so where on the furnace I would even hook it up

Comment: First thing to have done is an inspection and cleaning of the furnace, if not already done.  Need a furnace guy/girl that knows wood/oil furnaces, most don't and will do half of job.  90% of thermostats are for single fuel only and guess that goes to 100% for new wifis types.  You want a master/slave combination, with slave(oil) turning off wood and turning on oil, with wood set higher temp than oil(~5 to 10 degrees).

Comment: @crip659 -- it sounds like you're trying to create a crude approximation of a two-stage control there -- why wouldn't a two-stage heating thermostat with a relay added on to cut W1 out when W2 is energized work for this?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  That does seem like what he needs/wants.  If you know of the type that has WIFI/smart/remote control should make an answer.

Comment: R.e. the inspection - yep that is the challenge! Had the oil side inspected and serviced which I was happy with but he didn't look at the wood side. Going to call the nearby hearth/woodstove company to see if they could service the firebox or offer advice.
And yes that does sound like the type of system I want, once we're burning wood I'm thinking we would just mostly keep that side's thermostat set to something high to make sure the draft fan stays on any time there's a fire burning, and then once oil kicks in it shuts off that fan automatically

Comment: @crip659 higher-end Nests (not the Nest E, which is single stage only), Ecobees, and most of the Honeywell T-series Wifi stats all support two-stage systems

Comment: The additional comment I would make on an older system is to make sure your new system is milivolt compliant , most older systems are millivolt thermocouple controlled, some don’t like the old Mercury thermostats but one advantage they have is they can last for 50 years and they do not require additional power sometimes a separate transformer other times batteries or both. The newer systems usually allow programming and depending on the features may be able to calculate when the optimum temp to transfer, can’t do that with bi metallic mercury thermostats.